# How to make couple of minified files from different js files using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am new to grunt and task runners in JS, so this might seem a simple question but I have been unable to find exact working answer.

I have :

```
concat: {
            options: {
                // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
                separator: '\n\n'
            },
            dist: {
                // the files to concatenate
                src: ['scripts/app.js', 'scripts/constant.js'
                ],
                // the location of the resulting JS file
                dest: 'scripts/custom.js'
            }
        },
```

This task collects all my custom file together. What I want is to do similar thing for all my vendors file. Finally I should end up with two js only `custom.js` having my concatenated-minified code and `vendor.js` having concatenated-minfied libraries.

How do I write grunt configuration for this. Do I need to make two different tasks. If  I write the above code twice with different input files, it seems to run the last code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) can be configured to utilize [multiple-targets](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#multiple-targets).

For further documentation on this subject refer to [multi-tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks) and [Task Configuration and Targets](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) in the `grunt` documentation.

#### Gruntfile.js

For your scenario you need to configure your `concat` task similar to this (*Note:* the new `custom` and `vendor` targets):

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: '\n\n'
            },
            custom: {
                src: ['scripts/app.js', 'scripts/constant.js'],
                dest: 'scripts/output/custom.js'
            },
            vendor: {
                // Modify the src and dest paths as required...
                src: ['scripts/vendor/foo.js', 'scripts/vendor/baz.js'],
                dest: 'scripts/output/vendor.js'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.registerTask('concatenate', [
        'concat:custom', // <-- Targets in a task are called using a colon separator. 
        'concat:vendor'
    ]);

};
```

#### Running `concat`

Using the example gist provided above you can run the `concat` task via the CLI by typing the following command:

`$ grunt concatenate`

#### Configuring Options

If you require different configuration options for both the `custom` and `vendor` targets you will need to move the `options` object inside their respective targets. As explained [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#options).

*Note:* Using the example gist provided the `options` specified will apply to both targets.

Comment: Another great answer man. Really appreciate your way of providing elaborate answer and special thanks for the links.